# Thunderbird "undo send" feature (like in Gmail)?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I was wondering if there exists a thunderbird addon that gives similar functionality as Google's "undo send" feature?  This basically just delays the sent message for a few seconds allowing the user to cancel the send if desired.  I find this very useful in Gmail and would love the option now that I started using thunderbird.

I've seen the [send later](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) addon, but this isn't really what I want.  I want something very similar to Google's feature where it *automatically* delays each message before sending with an easy to access option to cancel the send.  Thanks!

Comment: This is easily done in Outlook and shields from sending an unfinished email by pressing ctrl-enter. In Thunderbird, I really miss the feature. It should be possible to indicate how much time the mail should remain in the out box before actually being sent. The procedure for Outlook: http://news.cnet.com/8301-13880_3-9929823-68.html

Comment: Question was also posted to the Mozilla support: http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/undo_send_do_we_have_it_can_we_get_it

Comment: @EricDarchis: Note that Thunderbird has a setting so that it asks for confirmation whenever the key combination for sending a mail is used.

Answer (score 5):

That add-on probably is what you want actually, as that is all Gmail's "undo send" option really does behind the scenes. It doesn't actually send your email's instantly, but rather delays them so you have the option to opt out before it's actually sent. The option doesn't actually dig into people's mailboxes and take the email out. Once it's sent, it's pushed to a different mail server. If everyone in the world used Gmail, maybe they could take it out of someone else's mailbox for you, but since everyone doesn't, this is how their "undo" feature actually works.

Comment: Yes I understand that.  Maybe its my fault for not trying out the addon first.  But is there a way to configure it so that for EVERY message I send it delays it by, say, 5 seconds? Thanks

Comment: Basically I'm saying that I completely understand that Gmail's feature does not pull the message out of peoples' inboxes but rather "queues" it locally before sending.  I'd just like to have the exact same functionality where the delay is automatically activated for every sent mail.

Comment: I don't know about presets as low as 5 seconds, but there are other presets for 15 and 30 minutes that this extension allows you to configure.

Comment: Thanks...it would be cool if someone made an extension that does what I'm looking for.  I've been saved many times by Gmail's undo feature where I quickly realize right after I hit send that I messed something up...

Comment: @josh - why don't you post a comment on the developer's page and ask for this feature? :)

Comment: @josh... that would make 2 of us :)

Comment: The [Send Later](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) add-on does support this. The second option in the preferences screen for the add-on is "'Send' delays messages by `x` minutes". If you check that option and set it to 1 minute, all messages you send will be copied to the Drafts folder then actually sent after a minute has passed. Noy exactly as smooth as the GMail experience, but probably as close as you can get in Thunderbird without writing a custom addon.

Answer (score 2):

Try the "[MagicSLR](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/magicslr/)" extension. You can add a "Send Later button" or use it to replace the Send button.

> MagicSLR extends functions and buttons to get and send messages. Many
>   users missed a combined "Get/Send" button in Thunderbird. MagicSLR
>   provides this button and more.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is relevant but I stumbled upon the ability to cancel a message after I have hit the "Send" button.  Usually there is a small window of opportunity after hitting "Send" in Thunderbird when Thunderbird is busy processing your request.  During this brief few seconds, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will actually cancel the sending of the message.  Of course, larger e-mails ie. with attachments, afford you a bit more time to cancel your e-mail.  I find this helpful if I have realized a typo or forgot to add content, I can stop the send process and go back and edit it.

Answer (score 1):

There's an Add-On which is called [QuoteAndComposeManager](https://freeshell.de/~kaosmos/quoteandcomposemanager-en.html) and a guide how to set a delay before sending just like in Gmail can be found [here](https://wphelp365.com/blog/how-to-delay-the-sending-of-emails-in-mozilla-thunderbird/). You have to install it from file and you can download it on the bottom of the website. It was designed also for other stuff but as the guide suggests just untick the other options and put in your time delay to usee it as the Gmail feature.

As it was pointed out "undo send" is nothing else than putting in a delay.

Comment: The URL above gives https warnings, here is a different one that works:
https://freeshell.de/~kaosmos/quoteandcomposemanager-en.html