# Email etiquette checker?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Sometimes, in the heat of getting a lot of things done, I don't read emails I send as closely as I should.  Is there an automated way to pop up warnings before a potentially-unpolite email is sent?  I'm thinking about something that would say "wait, why don't you have a 'please' or 'would you' in that message?"

I'm using Thunderbird 2 on Ubuntu 9.04.  I may be willing to switch email clients if another program offers this.  (Using a Mac is also an option, which I'd prefer.  Not sure if Mail.app has more options, though.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Caution: this message to *boss@myfirm.com* contains swearing. Do you really want to send it?". Yes, I guess it could be useful.

Comment: Haven't run into that one yet (thankfully), but that's the gist of it.  :)

Comment: Eudora had a similar thing: http://imgur.com/Hh4b3.png

Comment: @grawity:  That looks like exactly what I want.  Have you only seen it in Eudora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly slightly off topic but I've developed a habit of entering some random nonsense into the BCC field of any emails that I compose to external customers or to management.

This way I can't accidentally (or sleepily) click on the Send button and only realise afterwards that I haven't read it properly; until I manually remove the "erkgjherjghrejh" from the BCC field then the email won't get sent.

Comment: Interesting approach... I might adopt it for important emails that I dont' want to accidentally send.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but Gmail Labs has an Undo Send option that delays a message for a moment, so that if you hit send then realize you shouldn't have said that, you can stop the message before it goes out.  For more information, Google for "Gmail Undo Send".

A similar [feature for Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/105988/thunderbird-undo-send-feature-like-in-gmail) might help if one exists.

What you really want is to run a filter on outgoing messages. For example, you could move messages with certain words to a Suspicious Outgoing Messages folder.
For Thunderbird 2.0 there is [an extension for filtering outgoing messages](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/5538).

The extension documentation says 3.0 will have that built in, but a quick Web search offered no evidence of that.

Answer (score 1):

The [Check and Send](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-uS/thunderbird/addon/check-and-send/) extension lets you specify a list of words. It will then warn you before sending if any are present.

When installed, go to the extension's preferences and look under the "Words" tab. Punch in a list of your preferred swear-words here.

A nice feature is that it can skip over quoted text when searching, so if your boss was swearing at you in a previous message, it doesn't warn you for the rest of the conversation (unless you swear back).

It's also possible for it to warn if text is *not* present; you could use this with "please".

Comment: Interesting, that might fit the bill.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you use outlook, macros will help in checking the subject/body of messages

Comment: thankfully i don't think Outlook is available for Ubuntu.

Comment: Oops my fault - dint read the question properly :(

Comment: it could be used with Wine, in theory, so it's not *entirely* offtopic...